# PSpice circuit simulation does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why

Tags: pspice

I'm trying to simulate a differential amplifier circuit with an NMOS current source on PSpice. Even though all the connections seem right to me the simulations don't work when I run them. Below is the circuit and the error message I get.

[image: error message from PSpice]
[image: enter code here]

I would really appreciate it if I could get some help on this. I'm still quite new at PSpice so this feels pretty brain-rotting.

Comment: Can you try renaming the DC source "v1, v2" to something else without comma and space, like "VinCM" etc.

Comment: Yepp it works..Can i know whats wrong?

Comment: It seems it interpret the text after  the comma as another parameter. If its a bug or just a very old engine that doesnt like special characters, im not sure.

Comment: @Kid There's a space after the comma. SPICE syntax uses spaces to delineate pins, values, & operators. Unless you know the parser, avoid using special characters. v1_v2 would be a safer name.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that commas and other "special" characters other than letters and numbers is causing the problem.

The spice engine behind it is probably decades old (think DOS style) so it doesnt support this, and it does not interpret it like todays standards.